# How to prevent tinymce remove url source prefix when insert media plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, tinymce

I want to add This "https://www.youtube.com/embed/EWiMBUWyrqo" youtube link using media plugin. But link is converted into "//www.youtube.com/embed/EWiMBUWyrqo"
 How to resolve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Searched in tinymce docu and found http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:convert_urls

Via this link https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/url-conversion/

Could not test it but maybe it Will work for you

Answer (score 0):

tinyMCE uses the convert url (urlPattern) in the media plugin (plugin.js)
in file plugin.js (line 455):

Before:

```
 {
            regex: /youtu\.be\/([\w\-.]+)/,
            type: 'iframe', w: 560, h: 314,
            url: '//www.youtube.com/embed/$1',
            allowFullscreen: true
        },
```

After:

```
{
        regex: /youtu\.be\/([\w\-.]+)/,
        type: 'iframe', w: 560, h: 314,
        url: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1',
        allowFullscreen: true
    },
```

Note that if you install the plugin from node_modules when "npm i" or "npm update" all this is removed. Add plugin to assets/

Answer (score 0):

i  do face these problem and i solve it by edit the
tinymce_5.2.2\plugins\media\plugin.min.js

```
  H=[{regex:/youtu\.be\/([\w\-_\?&=.]+)/i,type:"iframe",w:560,h:314,url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1",allowFullscreen:!0},
{regex:/youtube\.com(.+)v=([^&]+)(&([a-z0-9&=\-_]+))?/i,type:"iframe",w:560,h:314,url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/$2?$4",allowFullscreen:!0},
{regex:/youtube.com\/embed\/([a-z0-9\?&=\-_]+)/i,type:"iframe",w:560,h:314,url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1",allowFullscreen:!0},
```

the full code for the fixed version of tinymce_5.2.2\plugins\media\plugin.min.js

is

```js
!function()
{
    "use strict";var e,t,r,n,i=tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.PluginManager"),o=tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.Env"),v=tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.util.Tools"),w=function(e){return e.getParam("media_scripts")},b=function(e){return e.getParam("audio_template_callback")},y=function(e){return e.getParam("video_template_callback")},a=function(e){return e.getParam("media_live_embeds",!0)},u=function(e){return e.getParam("media_filter_html",!0)},s=function(e){return e.getParam("media_url_resolver")},m=function(e){return e.getParam("media_alt_source",!0)},d=function(e){return e.getParam("media_poster",!0)},h=function(e){return e.getParam("media_dimensions",!0)},f=function(e){var t=e,r=function(){return t};return{get:r,set:function(e){t=e},clone:function(){return f(r())}}},c=function(){},l=function(e){return function(){return e}},p=l(!1),g=l(!0),x=function(){return O},O=(e=function(e){return e.isNone()},n={fold:function(e,t){return e()},is:p,isSome:p,isNone:g,getOr:r=function(e){return e},getOrThunk:t=function(e){return e()},getOrDie:function(e){throw new Error(e||"error: getOrDie called on none.")},getOrNull:l(null),getOrUndefined:l(undefined),or:r,orThunk:t,map:x,each:c,bind:x,exists:p,forall:g,filter:x,equals:e,equals_:e,toArray:function(){return[]},toString:l("none()")},Object.freeze&&Object.freeze(n),n),j=function(r){var e=l(r),t=function(){return i},n=function(e){return e(r)},i={fold:function(e,t){return t(r)},is:function(e){return r===e},isSome:g,isNone:p,getOr:e,getOrThunk:e,getOrDie:e,getOrNull:e,getOrUndefined:e,or:t,orThunk:t,map:function(e){return j(e(r))},each:function(e){e(r)},bind:n,exists:n,forall:n,filter:function(e){return e(r)?i:O},toArray:function(){return[r]},toString:function(){return"some("+r+")"},equals:function(e){return e.is(r)},equals_:function(e,t){return e.fold(p,function(e){return t(r,e)})}};return i},_=x,S=function(e){return null===e||e===undefined?O:j(e)},k=Object.hasOwnProperty,N=function(e,t){return M(e,t)?S(e[t]):_()},M=function(e,t){return k.call(e,t)},T=tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.dom.DOMUtils"),z=tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.html.SaxParser"),A=function(e,t){if(e)for(var r=0;r<e.length;r++)if(-1!==t.indexOf(e[r].filter))return e[r]},C=T.DOM,$=function(e){return e.replace(/px$/,"")},P=function(a,e){var c=f(!1),u={};return z({validate:!1,allow_conditional_comments:!0,special:"script,noscript",start:function(e,t){if(c.get());else if(M(t.map,"data-ephox-embed-iri"))c.set(!0),i=(n=t).map.style,o=i?C.parseStyle(i):{},u={type:"ephox-embed-iri",source1:n.map["data-ephox-embed-iri"],source2:"",poster:"",width:N(o,"max-width").map($).getOr(""),height:N(o,"max-height").map($).getOr("")};else{if(u.source1||"param"!==e||(u.source1=t.map.movie),"iframe"!==e&&"object"!==e&&"embed"!==e&&"video"!==e&&"audio"!==e||(u.type||(u.type=e),u=v.extend(t.map,u)),"script"===e){var r=A(a,t.map.src);if(!r)return;u={type:"script",source1:t.map.src,width:r.width,height:r.height}}"source"===e&&(u.source1?u.source2||(u.source2=t.map.src):u.source1=t.map.src),"img"!==e||u.poster||(u.poster=t.map.src)}var n,i,o}}).parse(e),u.source1=u.source1||u.src||u.data,u.source2=u.source2||"",u.poster=u.poster||"",u},F=tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.util.Promise"),D=function(e){var t={mp3:"audio/mpeg",wav:"audio/wav",mp4:"video/mp4",webm:"video/webm",ogg:"video/ogg",swf:"application/x-shockwave-flash"}[e.toLowerCase().split(".").pop()];return t||""},L=tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.html.Schema"),E=tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.html.Writer"),J=T.DOM,R=function(e){return/^[0-9.]+$/.test(e)?e+"px":e},U=function(e,t){for(var r in t){var n=""+t[r];if(e.map[r])for(var i=e.length;i--;){var o=e[i];o.name===r&&(n?(e.map[r]=n,o.value=n):(delete e.map[r],e.splice(i,1)))}else n&&(e.push({name:r,value:n}),e.map[r]=n)}},W=function(e,c,u){var s,l=E(),m=f(!1),d=0;return z({validate:!1,allow_conditional_comments:!0,special:"script,noscript",comment:function(e){l.comment(e)},cdata:function(e){l.cdata(e)},text:function(e,t){l.text(e,t)},start:function(e,t,r){if(m.get());else if(M(t.map,"data-ephox-embed-iri"))m.set(!0),n=c,o=(i=t).map.style,(a=o?J.parseStyle(o):{})["max-width"]=R(n.width),a["max-height"]=R(n.height),U(i,{style:J.serializeStyle(a)});else{switch(e){case"video":case"object":case"embed":case"img":case"iframe":c.height!==undefined&&c.width!==undefined&&U(t,{width:c.width,height:c.height})}if(u)switch(e){case"video":U(t,{poster:c.poster,src:""}),c.source2&&U(t,{src:""});break;case"iframe":U(t,{src:c.source1});break;case"source":if(++d<=2&&(U(t,{src:c["source"+d],type:c["source"+d+"mime"]}),!c["source"+d]))return;break;case"img":if(!c.poster)return;s=!0}}var n,i,o,a;l.start(e,t,r)},end:function(e){if(!m.get()){if("video"===e&&u)for(var t=1;t<=2;t++)if(c["source"+t]){var r=[];r.map={},d<t&&(U(r,{src:c["source"+t],type:c["source"+t+"mime"]}),l.start("source",r,!0))}if(c.poster&&"object"===e&&u&&!s){var n=[];n.map={},U(n,{src:c.poster,width:c.width,height:c.height}),l.start("img",n,!0)}}l.end(e)}},L({})).parse(e),l.getContent()},
    
    H=[{regex:/youtu\.be\/([\w\-_\?&=.]+)/i,type:"iframe",w:560,h:314,url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1",allowFullscreen:!0},
    {regex:/youtube\.com(.+)v=([^&]+)(&([a-z0-9&=\-_]+))?/i,type:"iframe",w:560,h:314,url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/$2?$4",allowFullscreen:!0},
    {regex:/youtube.com\/embed\/([a-z0-9\?&=\-_]+)/i,type:"iframe",w:560,h:314,url:"https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1",allowFullscreen:!0},
    
    {regex:/vimeo\.com\/([0-9]+)/,type:"iframe",w:425,h:350,url:"https://player.vimeo.com/video/$1?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=8dc7dc",allowFullscreen:!0},{regex:/vimeo\.com\/(.*)\/([0-9]+)/,type:"iframe",w:425,h:350,url:"https://player.vimeo.com/video/$2?title=0&amp;byline=0",allowFullscreen:!0},{regex:/maps\.google\.([a-z]{2,3})\/maps\/(.+)msid=(.+)/,type:"iframe",w:425,h:350,url:'//maps.google.com/maps/ms?msid=$2&output=embed"',allowFullscreen:!1},{regex:/dailymotion\.com\/video\/([^_]+)/,type:"iframe",w:480,h:270,url:"https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/$1",allowFullscreen:!0},{regex:/dai\.ly\/([^_]+)/,type:"iframe",w:480,h:270,url:"https://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/$1",allowFullscreen:!0}],I=function(r,e){var n=v.extend({},e);if(!n.source1&&(v.extend(n,P(w(r),n.embed)),!n.source1))return"";n.source2||(n.source2=""),n.poster||(n.poster=""),n.source1=r.convertURL(n.source1,"source"),n.source2=r.convertURL(n.source2,"source"),n.source1mime=D(n.source1),n.source2mime=D(n.source2),n.poster=r.convertURL(n.poster,"poster");var t,i,o=(t=n.source1,0<(i=H.filter(function(e){return e.regex.test(t)})).length?v.extend({},i[0],{url:function(e,t){for(var r=e.regex.exec(t),n=e.url,i=function(e){n=n.replace("$"+e,function(){return r[e]?r[e]:""})},o=0;o<r.length;o++)i(o);return n.replace(/\?$/,"")}(i[0],t)}):null);if(o&&(n.source1=o.url,n.type=o.type,n.allowFullscreen=o.allowFullscreen,n.width=n.width||o.w,n.height=n.height||o.h),n.embed)return W(n.embed,n,!0);var a=A(w(r),n.source1);a&&(n.type="script",n.width=a.width,n.height=a.height);var c,u,s,l,m,d,h,f,p=b(r),g=y(r);return n.width=n.width||300,n.height=n.height||150,v.each(n,function(e,t){n[t]=r.dom.encode(e)}),"iframe"===n.type?(f=(h=n).allowFullscreen?' allowFullscreen="1"':"",'<iframe src="'+h.source1+'" width="'+h.width+'" height="'+h.height+'"'+f+"></iframe>"):"application/x-shockwave-flash"===n.source1mime?(d='<object data="'+(m=n).source1+'" width="'+m.width+'" height="'+m.height+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">',m.poster&&(d+='<img src="'+m.poster+'" width="'+m.width+'" height="'+m.height+'" />'),d+="</object>"):-1!==n.source1mime.indexOf("audio")?(s=n,(l=p)?l(s):'<audio controls="controls" src="'+s.source1+'">'+(s.source2?'\n<source src="'+s.source2+'"'+(s.source2mime?' type="'+s.source2mime+'"':"")+" />\n":"")+"</audio>"):"script"===n.type?'<script src="'+n.source1+'"><\/script>':(c=n,(u=g)?u(c):'<video width="'+c.width+'" height="'+c.height+'"'+(c.poster?' poster="'+c.poster+'"':"")+' controls="controls">\n<source src="'+c.source1+'"'+(c.source1mime?' type="'+c.source1mime+'"':"")+" />\n"+(c.source2?'<source src="'+c.source2+'"'+(c.source2mime?' type="'+c.source2mime+'"':"")+" />\n":"")+"</video>")},q={},V=function(t){return function(e){return I(t,e)}},B=function(e,t){var r,n,i,o,a,c=s(e);return c?(i=t,o=V(e),a=c,new F(function(t,e){var r=function(e){return e.html&&(q[i.source1]=e),t({url:i.source1,html:e.html?e.html:o(i)})};q[i.source1]?r(q[i.source1]):a({url:i.source1},r,e)})):(r=t,n=V(e),new F(function(e){e({html:n(r),url:r.source1})}))},G=function(e){return q.hasOwnProperty(e)},K=function(t){return function(e){return e?e.style[t].replace(/px$/,""):""}},Q=function(n){return function(e,t){var r;e&&(e.style[n]=/^[0-9.]+$/.test(r=t)?r+"px":r)}},X={getMaxWidth:K("maxWidth"),getMaxHeight:K("maxHeight"),setMaxWidth:Q("maxWidth"),setMaxHeight:Q("maxHeight")},Y=function(e,t){e.state.set("oldVal",e.value()),t.state.set("oldVal",t.value())},Z=function(e,t){var r=e.find("#width")[0],n=e.find("#height")[0],i=e.find("#constrain")[0];r&&n&&i&&t(r,n,i.checked())},ee=function(e,t,r){var n=e.state.get("oldVal"),i=t.state.get("oldVal"),o=e.value(),a=t.value();r&&n&&i&&o&&a&&(o!==n?(a=Math.round(o/n*a),isNaN(a)||t.value(a)):(o=Math.round(a/i*o),isNaN(o)||e.value(o))),Y(e,t)},te=function(e){Z(e,ee)},re=function(e){var t=function(){e(function(e){te(e)})};return{type:"container",label:"Dimensions",layout:"flex",align:"center",spacing:5,items:[{name:"width",type:"textbox",maxLength:5,size:5,onchange:t,ariaLabel:"Width"},{type:"label",text:"x"},{name:"height",type:"textbox",maxLength:5,size:5,onchange:t,ariaLabel:"Height"},{name:"constrain",type:"checkbox",checked:!0,text:"Constrain proportions"}]}},ne=function(e){Z(e,Y)},ie=te,oe=o.ie&&o.ie<=8?"onChange":"onInput",ae=function(r){return function(e){var t=e&&e.msg?"Media embed handler error: "+e.msg:"Media embed handler threw unknown error.";r.notificationManager.open({type:"error",text:t})}},ce=function(i,o){return function(e){var t=e.html,r=i.find("#embed")[0],n=v.extend(P(w(o),t),{source1:e.url});i.fromJSON(n),r&&(r.value(t),ie(i))}},ue=function(e,t){var r=e.dom.select("img[data-mce-object]");e.insertContent(t),function(e,t){var r,n,i=e.dom.select("img[data-mce-object]");for(r=0;r<t.length;r++)for(n=i.length-1;0<=n;n--)t[r]===i[n]&&i.splice(n,1);e.selection.select(i[0])}(e,r),e.nodeChanged()},se=function(n){var i,t,e,r,o,a=[{name:"source1",type:"filepicker",filetype:"media",size:40,autofocus:!0,label:"Source",onpaste:function(){setTimeout(function(){B(n,i.toJSON()).then(ce(i,n))["catch"](ae(n))},1)},onchange:function(e){var r,t;B(n,i.toJSON()).then(ce(i,n))["catch"](ae(n)),r=i,t=e.meta,v.each(t,function(e,t){r.find("#"+t).value(e)})},onbeforecall:function(e){e.meta=i.toJSON()}}],c=[];if(m(n)&&c.push({name:"source2",type:"filepicker",filetype:"media",size:40,label:"Alternative source"}),d(n)&&c.push({name:"poster",type:"filepicker",filetype:"image",size:40,label:"Poster"}),h(n)){var u=re(function(e){e(i),t=i.toJSON(),i.find("#embed").value(W(t.embed,t))});a.push(u)}r=(e=n).selection.getNode(),o=r.getAttribute("data-ephox-embed-iri"),t=o?{source1:o,"data-ephox-embed-iri":o,width:X.getMaxWidth(r),height:X.getMaxHeight(r)}:r.getAttribute("data-mce-object")?P(w(e),e.serializer.serialize(r,{selection:!0})):{};var s={id:"mcemediasource",type:"textbox",flex:1,name:"embed",value:function(e){var t=e.selection.getNode();if(t.getAttribute("data-mce-object")||t.getAttribute("data-ephox-embed-iri"))return e.selection.getContent()}(n),multiline:!0,rows:5,label:"Source"};s[oe]=function(){t=v.extend({},P(w(n),this.value())),this.parent().parent().fromJSON(t)};var l=[{title:"General",type:"form",items:a},{title:"Embed",type:"container",layout:"flex",direction:"column",align:"stretch",padding:10,spacing:10,items:[{type:"label",text:"Paste your embed code below:",forId:"mcemediasource"},s]}];0<c.length&&l.push({title:"Advanced",type:"form",items:c}),i=n.windowManager.open({title:"Insert/edit media",data:t,bodyType:"tabpanel",body:l,onSubmit:function(){var t,e;ie(i),t=n,(e=i.toJSON()).embed=W(e.embed,e),e.embed&&G(e.source1)?ue(t,e.embed):B(t,e).then(function(e){ue(t,e.html)})["catch"](ae(t))}}),ne(i)},le=function(e){return{showDialog:function(){se(e)}}},me=function(e){e.addCommand("mceMedia",function(){se(e)})},de=tinymce.util.Tools.resolve("tinymce.html.Node"),he=function(o,e){if(!1===u(o))return e;var a,c=E();return z({validate:!1,allow_conditional_comments:!1,special:"script,noscript",comment:function(e){c.comment(e)},cdata:function(e){c.cdata(e)},text:function(e,t){c.text(e,t)},start:function(e,t,r){if(a=!0,"script"!==e&&"noscript"!==e&&"svg"!==e){for(var n=t.length-1;0<=n;n--){var i=t[n].name;0===i.indexOf("on")&&(delete t.map[i],t.splice(n,1)),"style"===i&&(t[n].value=o.dom.serializeStyle(o.dom.parseStyle(t[n].value),e))}c.start(e,t,r),a=!1}},end:function(e){a||c.end(e)}},L({})).parse(e),c.getContent()},fe=function(e,t){var r,n=t.name;return(r=new de("img",1)).shortEnded=!0,ge(e,t,r),r.attr({width:t.attr("width")||"300",height:t.attr("height")||("audio"===n?"30":"150"),style:t.attr("style"),src:o.transparentSrc,"data-mce-object":n,"class":"mce-object mce-object-"+n}),r},pe=function(e,t){var r,n,i,o=t.name;return(r=new de("span",1)).attr({contentEditable:"false",style:t.attr("style"),"data-mce-object":o,"class":"mce-preview-object mce-object-"+o}),ge(e,t,r),(n=new de(o,1)).attr({src:t.attr("src"),allowfullscreen:t.attr("allowfullscreen"),style:t.attr("style"),"class":t.attr("class"),width:t.attr("width"),height:t.attr("height"),frameborder:"0"}),(i=new de("span",1)).attr("class","mce-shim"),r.append(n),r.append(i),r},ge=function(e,t,r){var n,i,o,a,c;for(a=(o=t.attributes).length;a--;)n=o[a].name,i=o[a].value,"width"!==n&&"height"!==n&&"style"!==n&&("data"!==n&&"src"!==n||(i=e.convertURL(i,n)),r.attr("data-mce-p-"+n,i));(c=t.firstChild&&t.firstChild.value)&&(r.attr("data-mce-html",escape(he(e,c))),r.firstChild=null)},ve=function(e){for(;e=e.parent;)if(e.attr("data-ephox-embed-iri"))return!0;return!1},we=function(i){return function(e){for(var t,r,n=e.length;n--;)(t=e[n]).parent&&(t.parent.attr("data-mce-object")||("script"!==t.name||(r=A(w(i),t.attr("src"))))&&(r&&(r.width&&t.attr("width",r.width.toString()),r.height&&t.attr("height",r.height.toString())),"iframe"===t.name&&a(i)&&o.ceFalse?ve(t)||t.replace(pe(i,t)):ve(t)||t.replace(fe(i,t))))}},be=function(d){d.on("preInit",function(){var t=d.schema.getSpecialElements();v.each("video audio iframe object".split(" "),function(e){t[e]=new RegExp("</"+e+"[^>]*>","gi")});var r=d.schema.getBoolAttrs();v.each("webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen".split(" "),function(e){r[e]={}}),d.parser.addNodeFilter("iframe,video,audio,object,embed,script",we(d)),d.serializer.addAttributeFilter("data-mce-object",function(e,t){for(var r,n,i,o,a,c,u,s,l=e.length;l--;)if((r=e[l]).parent){for(u=r.attr(t),n=new de(u,1),"audio"!==u&&"script"!==u&&((s=r.attr("class"))&&-1!==s.indexOf("mce-preview-object")?n.attr({width:r.firstChild.attr("width"),height:r.firstChild.attr("height")}):n.attr({width:r.attr("width"),height:r.attr("height")})),n.attr({style:r.attr("style")}),i=(o=r.attributes).length;i--;){var m=o[i].name;0===m.indexOf("data-mce-p-")&&n.attr(m.substr(11),o[i].value)}"script"===u&&n.attr("type","text/javascript"),(a=r.attr("data-mce-html"))&&((c=new de("#text",3)).raw=!0,c.value=he(d,unescape(a)),n.append(c)),r.replace(n)}})}),d.on("setContent",function(){d.$("span.mce-preview-object").each(function(e,t){var r=d.$(t);0===r.find("span.mce-shim",t).length&&r.append('<span class="mce-shim"></span>')})})},ye=function(e){e.on("ResolveName",function(e){var t;1===e.target.nodeType&&(t=e.target.getAttribute("data-mce-object"))&&(e.name=t)})},xe=function(t){t.on("click keyup",function(){var e=t.selection.getNode();e&&t.dom.hasClass(e,"mce-preview-object")&&t.dom.getAttrib(e,"data-mce-selected")&&e.setAttribute("data-mce-selected","2")}),t.on("ObjectSelected",function(e){var t=e.target.getAttribute("data-mce-object");"audio"!==t&&"script"!==t||e.preventDefault()}),t.on("objectResized",function(e){var t,r=e.target;r.getAttribute("data-mce-object")&&(t=r.getAttribute("data-mce-html"))&&(t=unescape(t),r.setAttribute("data-mce-html",escape(W(t,{width:e.width,height:e.height}))))})},Oe=function(e){e.addButton("media",{tooltip:"Insert/edit media",cmd:"mceMedia",stateSelector:["img[data-mce-object]","span[data-mce-object]","div[data-ephox-embed-iri]"]}),e.addMenuItem("media",{icon:"media",text:"Media",cmd:"mceMedia",context:"insert",prependToContext:!0})};i.add("media",function(e){return me(e),Oe(e),ye(e),be(e),xe(e),le(e)})}();
```